# SELECT statement to get latest row

Tags: mysql, datetime, group-by

I've been assigned to do further development on a website which is, at this moment, a site for managers of convenience stores to monitor what articles that's inside the "grocery bag of the week". The former developer did very sloppy work so whenever the managers think: "Damn! I need to edit this article because I just entered the wrong value of it". They have to enter a new article with the same name and then they have two articles by the same name but with different price and DATE_TIME (the date and time when the article was entered). The database looks something like this:

```
________________________________________________
|___itemId___|___price___|______date_time______|
|     1      |    2.30   | 2012-01-01 00:00:00 |
|     2      |    1.50   | 2012-01-01 00:00:00 |
|     3      |    5.99   | 2012-01-01 00:00:00 |
|     4      |    0.99   | 2012-01-01 00:00:00 |
|     4      |    2.00   | 2012-01-01 00:10:00 |
|     4      |    4.99   | 2012-01-01 00:20:00 |
|     5      |   10.00   | 2012-01-01 00:00:00 |
|     6      |   39.99   | 2012-01-01 00:00:00 |
```

I was working on this **SELECT itemId, price, MAX(date_time) FROM myTable** to get the latest row of every item like this:

```
________________________________________________
|___itemId___|___price___|______date_time______|
|     1      |    2.30   | 2012-01-01 00:00:00 |
|     2      |    1.50   | 2012-01-01 00:00:00 |
|     3      |    5.99   | 2012-01-01 00:00:00 |
|     4      |    4.99   | 2012-01-01 00:20:00 |
|     5      |   10.00   | 2012-01-01 00:00:00 |
|     6      |   39.99   | 2012-01-01 00:00:00 |
```

But all i get is:

```
________________________________________________
|___itemId___|___price___|______date_time______|
|     4      |    4.99   | 2012-01-01 00:20:00 |
```

Can someone please help me on this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT itemId, price, MAX(date_time)
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY itemId
```

Answer (score 1):

try using either `group by` or `distinct`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t0.itemId, 
       t0.price, 
       t0.date_time 
FROM   myTable AS t0 
       LEFT JOIN myTable AS t1 
         ON t0.itemId = t1.itemId 
            AND t1.date_time > t0.date_time 
WHERE  t1.itemId IS NULL;
```